# How to LEFT JOIN on ANY of the matching clauses in R?

Tags: r, join, left-join, non-equi-join

could you please help me out with this:

I have a dataframe (`df1`) that has index of all articles published in the website's CMS. There's a column for current `URL` and a column of original URLs in case they were changed after publication (column name `Origin`):

| URL | Origin | ArticleID | Author | Category | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://example.com/article1 | https://example.com/article | 001 | AuthorName | Politics | 120 USD |
| https://example.com/article2 | https://example.com/article2 | 002 | AuthorName | Finance | 68 USD |

Next I have an huge dataframe (`df2`)with web analytics export for a timeframe. It has a date, just 1 column for URL and number of pageviews.

| PageviewDate | URL | Pageviews |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | https://example.com/article | 224544 |
| 2019-01-01 | https://example.com/article1 | 656565 |

How do I left join this with first dataframe but matching on either `URL` = `URL` OR `Origin` = `URL`

So that end result would look like this:

| PageviewDate | Pageviews | ArticleID | Author | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 881109 | 001 | AuthorName | Politics |

i.e `881109` is the result of adding up `224544` and `656565` that both related to the same article

I guess what I'm looking for is the equivalent of SQL syntax like:

````sql
LEFT JOIN ...`enter code here`
ON URL = URL
OR Origin = URL```
````

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://www.programmingr.com/tutorial/left-join-in-r/) or this [link](https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/join-in-r-merge-in-r/) also?

Comment: Yes, I did, but couldn't find any equivalent of `SQL` query like
```LEFT JOIN ...
ON URL = URL
OR Origin = URL```

Answer (score 3):

You could get dataframe 1 (`df1`) in long format so that both `Origin` and `URL` are in the same column and then perform the join with second dataframe (`df2`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(URL, Origin), values_to = 'URL') %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = 'URL') %>%
  select(-name)

#  ArticleID Author     Category name   URL                          PageviewDate Pageviews
#      <int> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>  <chr>                        <chr>            <int>
#1         1 AuthorName Politics URL    https://example.com/article1 2019-01-01      656565
#2         1 AuthorName Politics Origin https://example.com/article  2019-01-01      224544
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(URL = c("https://example.com/article1", "https://example.com/article2"
), Origin = c("https://example.com/article", "https://example.com/article2"
), ArticleID = 1:2, Author = c("AuthorName", "AuthorName"), 
Category = c("Politics", "Finance")), class = "data.frame",row.names =c(NA, -2L))


df2 <- structure(list(PageviewDate = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01"), 
    URL = c("https://example.com/article", "https://example.com/article1"), 
Pageviews = c(224544L, 656565L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```